# Press, hold and release on a View

Tags: android

I have a custom view, when the user presses and holds on the view, I want to change its main display, then change it back when they let go. Androids listeners dont seem to have some sort of onRelease function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //do something when pressed down

            return true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
           //do something when let go

           return true;
        }   
        return false;
    }
});
```

Did you try this? I am using this now and it works fine :)

Comment: this works on ACTION_DOWN, but its not detecting ACTION_UP

Comment: add return true to the ACTION_DOWN if statement

Comment: Also return true for ACTION_UP and then return false at the end instead of true...Let me know if that works!!!

Comment: I fixed my answer for you

Comment: Nice. You saved my day. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following xml in drawable directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

And set the view background to that drawable. Done :)

Comment: i may not have asked my question clearly. What i want is to to change the view when the user is pressing and holding, and change it back when they let go.

Comment: Yea the above will do that. State pressed is the action of pressing an holding, you change the view drawable to be of a different drawable. Then it is no longer pressed, the original drawable will come back. If you want to change more the view look (say do calculations and other work) then thats a different story